# Converting String to datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime

How would I convert the string `2014-05-19` to a datetime object in `Python` if I'm reading it from a `csv` file? Currently when I specify dtype=None, it reads in `2014-05-19` as a string, not a datetime.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

np.genfromtxt(inputFile, dtype=None,delimiter=' ')
```

**File**

```
2014-05-19 10
2014-05-20 11
2014-05-21 12
2014-05-22 13.29
2014-05-23 12.1
```

where the number after the string is a value associated with the date but not included in the `datetime` object

```
dataPoints = np.loadtxt(inputFile, dtype=None,delimiter=' ', converters = {0: datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')})
```

I receive the following message: `TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

how do I specify the format without actually stripping the string?

Comment: what is the number after the space?

Comment: Why do you have to use numpy? why not open the csv, split by comma, and strptime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have missing values you can use `numpy.loadtxt()`.

`numpy.genfromtxt()` also has the converters param.  (thx RickyA)

Using 'coverters' param and lambda function:

```
from datetime import datetime
datestr2num = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
np.genfromtxt(inputFile, delimiter=' ', converters = {0: datestr2num})
```

Where `0` is column index.

There is simpler way - use dtype param:

`np.genfromtxt(inputFile, dtype=['datetime64[D]', float], delimiter=' ')`

or more human readable using ('column name', type) tuple:

`np.genfromtxt(inputFile, dtype=[('Date', 'datetime64[D]'),('Value', float)], delimiter=' ')`

BTW IMHO *Load string as datetime in numpy* would be more accurate title.

Comment: but will this try to convert my associated value to a date as well?

Comment: I just edited. You indicate which column will be converted by index. So the answer is no :-)

Comment: BTW. [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) also has the converters param

Comment: @PiotrNawrot also, would datestr2num = '%Y-%m-%d' suffice?

Comment: @PiotrNawrot I'm still just a little confused by the datestr2num part, thanks.

Comment: @Auser I _refactored_ answerer and added new, simpler solution. I think it should be more clear.

Comment: @PiotrNawrot Thanks so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917271/load-data-from-csv-using-numpy Would you mind also taking a look at another related question of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the strptime function from the datetime module. I'm not sure what the numbers after the space should be, but this will format the year-month-day correctly into a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime

some_date = '2014-05-28'
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(some_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(parsed_date)
```