# Load Data from CSV using Numpy

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

**Data**

```
HOD,2012-1-3,1,5000
HOD,2012-1-4,1,5000
HOD,2012-1-5,1,5000
HOD,2012-1-6,1,5000
HOD,2012-1-9,1,5000
HOD,2012-1-10,1,5000

myData = np.genfromtxt(inputFile, dtype=[('Symbol',str),('Date', 'datetime64[D]'),('Value', int),('Allocation', long)], delimiter=',')
print myData
```

**Output**

```
('', datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1, 5000L)
('', datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1, 5000L)
('', datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1, 5000L)
('', datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1, 5000L)
('', datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 0, 0), 1, 5000L)
```

Why are my strings lost?

Comment: Note that your dates are not being imported correctly, as well :) _(Zero padding for the month and day may help...)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String dtype require you to specify length:

```
dtype=[('Symbol', 'S3'), ...]
```

or

```
dtype=[('Symbol', (str, 3)), ...]
```

If you want arbitrary-length string, specify `object` as a type; it will allow any object to be assigned.